# How to check react-native version of project?

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a react-native component and I use events but my native module doesn't build on older version of react when sending events were by `bridge.eventDispatcher..`

So is there a way to check the version to switch between react and react-native modules implementations?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know the version of react and react-native from inside the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**check remote version of react-native**

> npm info react-native version

**check version of react-native**

> npm list --depth=0

**remove older version of react-native**

> npm --save remove react react-native

**Install x version of react-native**

> npm --save react-native@x.x.x    //maybe 0.30.0

Note that you can use these commands for all modules in node_modules folder. Also you can check your react-native version in package.json file which is in your project.

'Before doing any changes be sure that problem is about incompability between react and react-native version' so had better share complete error log.

Answer (score 5):

If you type `react-native --version` inside a project, it will tell you the installed version (tested with `react-native-cli` v. 2.0.1).

Comment: This does not work for me.